# What's the difference between "wp" and "wp_loaded"?

Tags: hooks

What's the difference between `wp` and `wp_loaded`? Which one is earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) is fired once WordPress, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.

[`wp`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) runs immediately after the global WP class object is set up.

`wp_loaded` fires before `wp`. See the [actions run during a typical request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).